# updating a line plot in matlab using data from arduino serial print, why am I getting "array in wrong shape" error?

Tags: matlab, arduino

I have a version of this code which works, where I individually assign each value to a new variable each time. I was told I should keep it as a matrix and use indexing to access the individual values to make the code better (and when I was making some requested changes I realised it would be much simpler if I could get it working this way). I'm reading 10 temperature values from arduino serial print and plotting them on a graph. With the current code I am getting this error:

Warning: Error creating or updating Line
 Error in value of one or more of the following properties:  XData YData
 Array is wrong shape or size

I don't fully understand how the tic/toc section of this code works and I think that's probably where I'm going wrong. Thank you for your help! (code below)

```
clear all;
clc;
delete(instrfindall); %pre-emptively close all ports
a = serial('COM6', 'BaudRate', 9600);
flushinput(a);

fopen(a); %initiate arduino connection


Tmax = 180; %(total data collection time (s))
Ts = 1; %(sampling interval (s))
SensorNum = 10; %(Number of PT100s connected to board)



%create live data figure window
figure,
grid on,
grid minor,
xlabel ('Time (s)'), ylabel('Temperature (K)'),

%read and plot data from arduino
ii = 0;
dataa = 0;
t = 0;

tic % Start timer

while toc <= Tmax
    ii = ii + 1;
    dataa = fscanf(a);
    y = strsplit (dataa, ',');
    if(length(str2double(y))<SensorNum)
        disp("Output length mismatch");
        y = NaN(10,1);
    end
    flushinput(a);
    t(ii) = toc;
    if ii > 1
        T = toc - t(ii-1);
        while T < Ts
            T = toc - t(ii-1);
        end
    end
    t(ii) = toc;


    %% Plot live data
    if ii > 1
        x = t(ii);
        for i = 1:SensorNum
            line(x, (y{i}))
        end
        drawnow
    end

end
fclose(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `line(x, (y{i}))` with `line(x, str2double(y{i}))`.

You are getting a warning message, because `y{i}` is a characters array, and not a scalar value.

`y = strsplit (dataa, ',');` returns cell array like `{'11.1'}` `{'22.2'}` `{'33.3'}`... where each cell is a characters array ("string").

Executing `line(x, (y{i}))`, is equivalent to executing `line(1, '11.1')`, which result the warning message.

Remark: My answer applies only the warning message - I didn't check for other issues in your code.